# Labview: how to set the time range in a Waveform Chart

Tags: charts, range, labview, waveform

I have a Waveform Chart in Labview. I know that I can change its range using the "Plot History Length" property. The problem is that I don't add the points to the plot regularly, so I can't compute the number of point I want to be displayed.

Is there a way to inform Labview that I want only the points from last, let's say, 20 minutes to be displayed?

I want to display an absolute time, so setting range to 20 min won't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use **X-Y graph** instead of Waveform chart, and assign your time data to the X axis.

OR: Use waveform chart, select absolute time, modify min.range and max.range properties of Time axis to show up the range **Current time -20** to **Current time**
[image]

Comment: The problem with adjusting the properties of the time axis is that adding a point to the WaveForm Charts resets the default range (automatic or chosen in the edit mode). So if I adjust the range after adding a point, for a very short time I can see the full range and if I adjust it after adding a point, it has no effect And when I use the XY graph, I won't be able to display an absolute time

Comment: Nevermind, setting the minimum and maximumt ime range works fine when I removed the "autoscale" option. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Use the right tool for the job, being the Waveform Graph instead of the Waveform Chart. Takes a 2D array of points so you can have arbitrary X axis spacing.